# Javascript function with PHP throwing a "Illegally Formed XML Syntax" error

Tags: php, javascript, xml, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn some javascript and i'm having trouble figuring out why my code is incorrect (i'm sure i'm doing something wrong lol), but anyways I am trying to create a login page so that when the form is submitted javascript will call a function that checks if the login is in a mysql database and then checks the validity of the password for the user if they exist. however I am getting an error (Illegally Formed XML Syntax) i cannot resolve. I'm really confused, mostly because netbeans is saying it is a xml syntax error and i'm not using xml. here is the code in question:

```
function validateLogin(login){

  login.addEventListener("input", function() {
    $value = login.value;
    if (<?php
    //connect to mysql
    mysql_connect(host, user, pass) or die(mysql_error());
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    echo("alert('MYSQL Connected.');");
    echo("</script>");
    //select db
    mysql_select_db() or die(mysql_error());
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    echo("alert('MYSQL Database Selected.');");
    echo("</script>");
    //query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins") or die(mysql_error()); 
    //check results against given login
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      if($row[login] == $value){
        echo("true");
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    echo("false");
    exit(0);
      ?>) {
      login.setCustomValidity("Invalid Login. Please Click 'Register' Below.")
    } else {
      login.setCustomValidity("")
    }

  });
}
```

the code is in an external js file and the error throws on the last line. Also from reading i understand best practices is to not mix js and php so how would i got about separating them but maintaining the functionality i need?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix PHP and JavaScript in this way as *all* of your PHP has already executed on the server before *any* of your JavaScript executes on the client.

The error is because the client is receiving and failing to execute this as JavaScript:

```
function validateLogin(login){

  login.addEventListener("input", function() {
    $value = login.value;
    if (<script type='text/javascript'>alert('MYSQL Connected.');</script>...
// etc.
```

To interact with PHP from the client, you'll have to make another HTTP request -- either by `<a>` click, `<form>` submit, or Ajax request (using [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for brevity; see [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for further details):

```
function validateLogin(login){
  login.addEventListener("input", function() {
    $.post('/validateLogin.php', { login: login }, function (result) {
      if (result === "true") {
        login.setCustomValidity("Invalid Login. Please Click 'Register' Below.")
      } else {
        login.setCustomValidity("")
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Adjust the URL, `/validateLogin.php`, as needed; but create a PHP file for this URL similar to:

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['login'];

mysql_connect(host, user, pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db() or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if($row[login] == $value){
    echo("true");
    exit(0);
  }
}
echo("false");
exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: okay, i get it now, thank you so much for such a detailed response.

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong? You simply break your JavaScript by inserting `<script>` parts to your `if` condition. So you get `if (<script type='text/javascript'>alert('MYSQL Connected.');</script>...` and so on... Next thing: you're trying to match `$value`, which is JavaScript variable, with `$row[login]` in PHP loop - you don't have `$value` there! These are separated codes. It's all wrong.

Jonathan Lonowski explained it very good how you should do this.

Comment: I don't understand - what's wrong with my answer that I got vote down? I was writing answer but popup message showed that somebody (Jonathan) answered, I loaded his post and thought it's complete and I don't have to write everything second time, so I just send what I had. It is not a solution, but it describe what is wrong..